# How can i color each cluster?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I tried to make clustering for my data, the code is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
import itertools
import matplotlib.cm
from sklearn import manifold

xx = pd.read_csv('distances.data',sep=" ",header=None)
NL=max(xx[0])
ND=max(xx[1])
if NL>ND:
    ND=NL 
N = len(xx)    
dist=np.zeros([ND,ND])
for i in range(N):
    ii = xx[0][i]-1
    jj = xx[1][i]-1
    dist[ii][jj]=xx[2][i]
    dist[jj][ii]=xx[2][i]

print("start")
mds = manifold.MDS(max_iter=200, eps=1e-4, n_init=1,dissimilarity='precomputed',random_state=0)
dp_mds = mds.fit_transform(dist)
plt.scatter(dp_mds[:, 0], dp_mds[:, 1])
plt.savefig("1.jpg")
```

and got the shape like this for my data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QyIl.jpg)
but need each cluster has a different color , how can i do it , please ?

can i get like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIozS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to utilize `c` and `cmap`:

```
colors = dict(c=dp_mds[:, 0], cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', 6))
plt.scatter(dp_mds[:, 0], dp_mds[:, 1], **colors)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. i edit the post with the result and the picture that i need to get it

Comment: I'll admit that I don't fully understand what you're doing, but it does look like where I have `c=dp_mds[:, 0]` will need to be replaced with whatever divides one cluster from another.

Comment: Thanks for your time , i need to color each cluster with a different color like the image i attached in the post

Comment: i got from your code that i can control the color by c=dp_mds[:, 0] orc=dp_mds[:, 1] but how can i use it to control the color of each cluster like the example i posted

Comment: If you were to look at the data in a table, how would you know which cluster it was in?

Comment: that is my problem how to catch them or control them , i saw the points clustered but couldn't get it

Comment: i tried to control it by `labels = dp_mds.labels_` but got `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'labels_'`